# Is the direct product of Euclidean rings (not necessarily integral domains) also Euclidean?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

And if it is, how do you define division and an Euclidean function?

(The question was put on hold asking for context information, definitions, motivation, etc; and in the meantime I found the answer to my question, but I'll write it down here for completeness.)

The most basic example is $\Bbb Z$, that is an Euclidean ring with the absolute value as Euclidean function: For $a,b \in \Bbb Z$ with $b \neq 0$, there exist $q,r \in \Bbb Z$ with $a = bq + r$ and $|r| < |b|$.

Now take $\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z$. Is it an Euclidean ring? What would be an Euclidean function for this ring?

Update:
I was trying to define an Euclidean function with values in the natural numbers, and that works for integral domains but doesn't work for more general rings with zero-divisors. For example, $\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z$ has no Euclidean function $\varphi: \Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z \rightarrow \Bbb N$ (Fletcher [1]).

Samuel [2] defines an Euclidean ring $R$ with a map $\varphi:R \rightarrow W$, $(W,\leq)$ a well-ordered set, such that for $a,b \in R$ with $b \neq 0$, there exist $q,r \in R$ with $a = bq + r$ and $\varphi(r) < \varphi(b)$, and shows that a product of Euclidean rings is Euclidean in this sense. And this answers my question.

The notion of Euclidean rings that are not necessarily domains is useful because some algorithms can be generalized to work over general Euclidean rings, even with zero-divisors. For example, Magma considers $\Bbb Z/m\Bbb Z$ an Euclidean ring, and in particular $\Bbb Z/p^k\Bbb Z$, as well as other Galois rings, are all Euclidean rings, and it can compute Groebner bases in polynomial rings over these rings. I'm implementing algorithms for commutative algebra and I want to compute with $R$-modules as general as possible. I'm looking at generalizations of Buchberger's, HNF, etc, and I want more examples of rings where I can solve linear systems. That's what motivated my original question.

[1] C.R. Fletcher, Euclidean rings, J. London Math. Soc. 41 (1971), 79-82

[2] P. Samuel, About Euclidean rings, J. Algebra 19 (1971), 282-301

Comment: I’m not sure I know what the “ring product” of two rings might be.

Comment: Certainly the Cartesian product of two integral domains is not an integral domain. One normally takes a Euclidean "ring" to be an Euclidean domain.

Comment: Have you looked at examples? Some examples of euclidean rings are fields $k$, the ring of integers $\mathbb{Z}$, polynomial rings over fields in one variable $k[T]$ or discrete valuation rings like the ring of $p$-adic integers $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

Comment: @ThorWittich Yes, and those are integral domains. But some authors define Euclidean rings without the requirement of having no zero-divisors, and in this sense $Z/mZ$ is also Euclidean. I'm interested in building more examples to test some algorithms, that's why I'd like to implement Euclidean division in product rings if possible.

Comment: Yes, that is why I was asking wether you were able to define a euclidean map on products of some examples such that you perhaps can generalize from these.

Comment: @ThorWittich Yes, actually I did try examples like $\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z$. The first thing I tried is defining quotient and remainder component-wise, and the Euclidean function as the sum of Euclidean functions for each component. This works as long as none of the components is 0. I expect it would be possible to extend it to the case of some but not all components being 0, I'll grab again paper and pencil and see if I can get it right. Thanks!